# Where was I wrong in my reasoning?

Tags: python

I'm an absolute beginner in programming in Python and this is my first program in Project Euler (problem 1).

Problem 1 in Project Euler asks:

> If we list all the natural numbers below 10 that are multiples of 3 or
>   5, we get 3, 5, 6 and 9. The sum of these multiples is 23.
>
> Find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000.

I feel like my reasoning is wrong somewhere, but I can't see where or why? I get 266333.

```
i=0
s=0
j=0
r=0

while i<1000:
  s=s+i
  i=i+3

while j<1000:
  r=r+j
  j=j+5
print("sum=",s+r)
```

Comment: Could you explain what your problem is? Your question has to be self-contained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're adding some numbers twice. 15, for example, is a multiple of 3 and 5, but you shouldn't add it twice.

I'd do something simpler using modulo, and only one loop.

Example (haven't tested):

```
x=0
y=0

while x<1000
   if (x%5==0 or x%3==0):
      y=y+x
   x+=1

print("Sum equals ",y)
```

Answer (score 2):

The question is:

> Find the sum of all multiples of `3` or `5` below `1000`.

All you need to do here is loop through the numbers below `1000`, if the number is divisible by `3`(`i % 3 == 0`) or `5`(`i % 5 == 0`), append it to a list `multiples` and print the sum of all the elements of `multiples`(`sum(multiples)`).

```
multiples = []

for i in range(1000):
    if i % 3 == 0 or i % 5 == 0:
        multiples.append(i)

print sum(multiples)
# 233168
```

More simplified code:

```
print sum([i for i in range(1000) if i % 3 == 0 or i % 5 == 0])
# 233168
```